# How to send an array/List with ajax and jquery. Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415 ()

Tags: html, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new with Jquery Ajax, I am trying to send an array via post. In the following way.

```
$(function(){
    $("#btnSave").click(function(){         
       
        var datos = new Array();

        $("#imgCurrent tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);

            var id =row.find("td:eq(0)").text();//.html();;

            var data=
            {
                RepositoryCatalogueID: id
            }

            datos.push(data);
        });    

        
        var url = "@Url.Action("EditPosition","Carrusel")";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'json',
            data: (datos),
            success: function (data) {
                $.alert({
                    icon: "~/Content/Images/success.png",
                    title: 'Restaurar Imagen',
                    content: 'Restauración exitosa.',
                });
            }
        })
        
        
    });
});
```

An object of this type is received in my controller.

```
public JsonResult EditPosition([FromBody] IEnumerable<CarruselViewModel> model)
    {
        bool success = false;
        JsonResult jResult;
        string message = string.Empty;}
```

It throws me the error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 415()

And it never enters the controller

Answer (score 0):

you need to cast your data to json. use this :

```
data: JSON.stringify(datos),
```

also make sure you put [HttpPost] attribute on top of your action method;

```
[HttpPost]    
public JsonResult EditPosition([FromBody] IEnumerable<CarruselViewModel> 
model)
{
    bool success = false;
    JsonResult jResult;
    string message = string.Empty;
}
```